# VB6.0 Automation error

Tags: vb6

I'm currently working on a VB6.0 application which is giving an automation error which isn't very consistent (Sometimes the code works then crashes after several successful iterations).

```
Dim example As String
```

...

```
On Error GoTo ERROR
example = UCase$(Replace(form.UniTextBox(1).Text, " ", ""))
ERROR:
debug.print("ERROR: " & Err.description)
```

This the section of code which I've identified causes the automation error. The root cause seems to lie when the computer is set up as Polish with Windows 7 running. When English locale is set there are no issues.

What is causing this issue?

Any advice or tips would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Report this bug to the authors of `UniTextBox` custom control.

Answer (score 0):

Controls are ANSI not unicode. COM is unicode not ANSI. That string is being converted back and forth by Windows and VB.

Windows, which controls are, are either ANSI or Unicode. VB6 was written when most computers only had ANSI windows, hence all API calls (which creating a window require) are ANSI calls. Send unicode to an ANSI window and Windows will convert it to ANSI first. Ask VB to do API calls or Forms and it will convert the unicode string to ANSI.

See StrConv, byte arrays can act as unicode strings, and also see system settings in Regional Options for non unicode programs.